# Reconnect to the internet automatically and disappear label

Tags: ios, swift, networking, label, wifi

Now I want to implement the detect network from the beginning into the app will detect whether the link network，assuming that the user cuts off the network on the way, the screen will display a label and imageView, if the network is reconnected, you can automatically display the information and let label and imageView disappear, but now I do not know how to automatically detect Network, and label and imageView how to put the center of the screen (not using storyboard), thank you!

and here is my code:

```
func laodingTableviewData() {
    self.tableView.isHidden = true
    let activityIndicatorView = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame:CGRect(x:ActivityConstraint.Activity.offsetX, y:ActivityConstraint.Activity.offsetY , width:80.0, height:80.0), type: .ballSpinFadeLoader, color: ActivityConstraint.Activity.color, padding: 20)

    self.view.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
    activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
    //detect network
    guard  Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true else {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1.5) {
            self.failNetworkAlert()
            self.failNetworkOutlet()
            activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
        }


        return
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1.5) {
        self.bulletinBoards = BulletinBoard.downloadAllBulletinBoard()
        self.tableView.isHidden = false
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
    }

}
```

Create label and imageView:

```
func failNetworkOutlet() {
    let w = self.view.frame.width/2
    let h = self.view.frame.height/2
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: -30, y: 0, width: 250, height: 21))
    label.center = CGPoint(x: w+5, y: h)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.text = "Please confirm that you are connected to the web"
    label.font = label.font.withSize(20)
    label.tintColor = UIColor.gray


    let imageViewObject = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x: w-25, y: h-85, width: 60, height: 60))
    imageViewObject.image = UIImage(named:"ic_settings_input_antenna_48pt")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    imageViewObject.tintColor = UIColor.gray

    self.view.addSubview(imageViewObject)
    self.view.addSubview(label)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Apologies, I know this is a communication issue. What's the issue? What to do if network connection is lost? Lost and then regained? Or something related to layout (you state *how to put the center of the screen (not using storyboard)*). If you can clarify a bit more, maybe we can help.

Comment: If there is no network now, showing label and imageview, when I re-connect the network, what method should be used to update the page (let label and imageview disappear), to use the button to trigger or there are other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the network notifications from reachability. Then post some sorts of notification so that we would know the network status

```
 import UIKit
import ReachabilitySwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let reachability = Reachability()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    checkNetworkStatus()
}


fileprivate func checkNetworkStatus() {

    if let reachability = reachability {
        reachability.whenReachable = { [unowned self] reachable in
            self.postNetworkStatusChangedNotification(to: true)
        }

        reachability.whenUnreachable = { [unowned self] unreachable in
            self.postNetworkStatusChangedNotification(to: false)
        }

        //start the notifier
        do {
            try reachability.startNotifier()
        }
        catch {
            print("Unable to start the network notifier")
        }
    }
}

func postNetworkStatusChangedNotification(to acquired:Bool) {
    //we will post notification
    if acquired {
        print("\n=== Internet Acess Acquired ===\n")
    }
    else {

        print("\n=== Lost Internet Access ===\n")
    }
}

}
```

When this is started it will notify whenever network status has been changed.

Comment: What is reachability after if let reachability = , it's that(https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift)?

Comment: yes, using same Reachability Library. I just have this variable  *let reachability = Reachability()*

Comment: It will give you optional reachability back, that's why there is *let reachability = reachability*

Comment: ok, but it's say capture 'self' was never used from [unowned self]

Comment: yes, that's because we are not using self inside the block. It is there because I was using self to call some method. you can create new function say *func postNotification(){}* and call *self.postNotification()*

Comment: try simple things first. Add this method to any of one viewcontroller -> call this from viewDidLoad -> run the app. you should see it prints (Internet Acess Acquired). Now turn of the internet. When you come back to the app it will print (Lost Internet Access). If that works then it's upto you how you make use of it. Because it's tested code from live app

Comment: OK,I'll try it now

Comment: When I closed wifi return "Lost Internet Access",and I opened wifi it's still return "Lost Internet Access"(Did not stop working),Is there a way for it to keep the state of the network?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148950/discussion-between-kathayatnk-and-).